# how do I limit the characters in selected row and con-cat with '...'

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-5

I have a query which return a column named `comment`. I want to limit the number of characters returned by select statement to 50 and if the `comment` row contain more than 50 characters, I want to append `...` at the end of it. How can i achieve this using on SQL query ?

Here is the query for my question.

`select comment from mip`
`where active = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MySQL's IF function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
select
    IF(LENGTH(comment) > 50,CONCAT(LEFT(comment,50),'...'),comment) comment
from mip where active = 1;
```

or

```
select
    IF(LENGTH(comment) > 50,CONCAT(SUBSTR(comment,1,50),'...'),comment) comment
from mip where active = 1;
```

Comment: Assuming you indeed intend to count characters and not bytes, for character data if the character set is multi-byte such as UNICODE ucs-2, utf-8, this will produce the wrong results or cause an error. The function to always use in that case is CHAR_LENGTH() or it's synonym CHARACTER_LENGTH() cf. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length